# Fourier transform of $f(x)=1/x^n$ at physicist level of rigour

Tags: fourier-transform, complex-numbers, dirac-delta-distributions

Functions such as $f(x)=1/x^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer and $x$ is a real variable in $-\infty\leq x\leq \infty$, strictly do not have Fourier transforms. But when applied to physics, can we regularize such Fourier transforms by excluding problematic points such as $x=0$, and derive some compact formula for it which shows the singularities clearly? I did ask a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619133/compact-formula-for-the-fourier-transform-of-xn-exists) on Mathematics StackExchange and I would like to see physicists' take on this.

Comment: Just go  to your [tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions,_one-dimensional), number 310.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want. :-)

Answer (score 1):

These functions do possess a Fourier transform, but it is not in the space of functions. You have to pose the problem in the space of distributions.
Distributions are essential in the Fourier transform theory applied to Physics.
The most famous distribution in Physics is probably Dirac's Delta $\delta(x)$.
In this case [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) provides you with generous information on the topic.